# Webdriver.io Scroll List

Tags: node.js, e2e-testing, webdriver-io, codeceptjs

I use CodeceptJS with webdriver.io as helper to do e2e test for a website. There is a ul (unordered list) and I want to scroll down to this list. There is scroll bar and I used buttonDown and buttonUp methods on the scroll bar to perform but couldn't figure it out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Give us a [MCVE] please!

Answer (score 1):

To scroll down:

```
client
.url('https://www.yourwebsite.com')
.leftClick('#yourtable') // <-- should also work with .click()
.scroll(0, 500) // the higher the more we scroll
```

to use keys make sure to click on the list div box before that the emulated mouse is at the item you want to scroll down. Then you can press the down key to go down:

```
 /*
  \uE014    "ArrowRight"
  \uE015    "ArrowDown"
 */

client
.leftClick('#yourtable') // <-- should also work with .click()
.keys('ArrowDown')
.keys('ArrowDown')
.keys('ArrowDown')
// or
.keys('\uE015')
.keys('\uE015')
.keys('\uE015')
```

Source: [api/protocol/keys.html](http://webdriver.io/api/protocol/keys.html)